# Youtube API Video searchquery - to include statistics and snippet info

Tags: youtube-api

I know nothing about coding.

But I'm trying to use the Youtube API search query: [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it) or [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) to include results that include the parameters viewCount, likeCount, dislikeCount, related videos, and publication date.

When I use link and input snippet as the part 1 the results include viewCount and publication date but not the other parameters. When I use link 2 and input statistics I get the other parameters but not the snippet information.

What query can I use to include both?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [2nd link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) and include "snippet" in the "part" field. So basically it will have two values separated by comma like "statistics, snippet"

your request should look like the following:

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```